# rsync multiple paths from one server to another server

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I want to copy files from one server to another server, and I have more than one path for the files.
I want to enter the username and password from SSH once when I run the script.
And how can I repeat the script in more than one path/directory di?

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install shpass -y
read -p "enter ssh source server : " src_server
read -p "enter ssh username for $src_server : " src_ssh_user
echo

mkdir -p /directory/folder1/ 2>/dev/null
echo "syncing directory $addons_path"
sudo rsync -av --rsh=ssh $src_ssh_user@$src_server:/directory/folder1/ /directory/folder1/


mkdir -p /directory/folder2/ 2>/dev/null
echo "syncing directory $addons_path"
sudo rsync -av --rsh=ssh $src_ssh_user@$src_server:/directory/folder2/ /directory/folder2/
```

Comment: Why are you installing `sshpass` if you are not using it? Are you trying to ask how to use `sshpass`?

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is with a for loop

```
#!/bin/bash
PATHS=$1
sudo apt-get install shpass -y
read -p "enter ssh source server : " src_server
read -p "enter ssh username for $src_server : " src_ssh_user
echo

for path in $PATHS
do
   mkdir -p $path 2>/dev/null
   echo "syncing directory $addons_path"
   sudo rsync -av --rsh=ssh $src_ssh_user@$src_server:$path $path

done
```

And execute the script

```
./myscript "/directory/folder1/ /directory/folder2/"
```